# How to use DataTemplateSelector on TreeViewItem's template?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have a `TreeView` with a custom resource dictionary for its `TreeViewItems` template.

I need to be able to programatically change the template for each `TreeViewItem` based on its binding's value.

As far as I can tell, I can't access the binding from the `ResourceDictionary` xaml.

I think I need to extend the `TreeView` with my own userControl, but I'm not sure what I need to actually add to it to achieve what I want.

Thanks in advance.

```
<TreeView Name="dirTree" AlternationCount="2" Background="#FAFAFA"
                       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Visible"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource tuningDataTemplateSelector}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="UI/Styles/TunerTreeViewStyle.xaml" />
            </TreeView.Resources>

        </TreeView>
```

This is the treeview, and as you can see I have an ItemTemplateSelector set, but this only changes the contents. I need to add a selector for the TreeViewItem control's template itself. So I would need to add it to the TunerTreeViewStyle.xaml but I don't think you can get the bound data from there.

Comment: What's the problem with using a DataTemplateSelector?

Comment: Well nothing, I'd prefer to use it. That's my question, how can I? Because there's no binding access in the Resource Dictionary, and that's the template I need to change, not the content inside of it.

I already have hierarchicaldatatemplates in use for the content but I need to affect the full TreeViewItem template.

Comment: You should just return the appropriate template from the selector. What do you mean by "binding access"?

Comment: I don't think you're following, I'll update my question with some code shortly.

I'm overriding the treeview control's appearance via a ResourceDictionary.
So I would need to add a datatemplateselector to the ResourceDictionary. 

The datatemplateselector would need to know what the current binding is to make its decisions. I can't do that if I can't access the bindings from inside ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an `ItemTemplateSelector` to change the `ControlTemplate` of a `TreeViewItem`.

If you want to do this you could try to define an `ItemContainerStyle` with a `DataTrigger` that sets the `Template` property of the `TreeViewItem` based on some source property, e.g.:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Value="A">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ResourceA}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Value="B">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ResourceB}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <!-- ... -->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Seems clear to me now, sorry I figured I was off track but didn't really know where I should actually be triggering this.