# How to add conditional template of TreeView.Resources in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to have a conditional XAML that selects whether this `TreeView.Resources` or the other.

I am using [MaterialDesignInXAML toolkit](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes)'s `Card` and inside it is the `TreeView`.

Let's say I have a collection of **Fruits** that has another collection inside called **Trees**.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domain:Tree}" ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
        // tree information here ...
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domain:Fruit}">
        // fruit information here ...
    </DataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Problem here is, there are fruits that don't grow from trees. So what I want is to have another resource but still will continue the template.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domain:Fruit}">
        // fruit information here
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

I want my output to be look like this:

```
> Apple Tree
    - Apples
> Mango Tree
    - Mangoes
> Watermelon
```

**Edit**:

I used **@BionicCode**'s second suggestion which is to use `DataTemplateSelector`. I added this to my XAML:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <domain:DtmSelector x:Key="DtmSelector">
            <domain:DtmSelector.WithTree>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domain:Tree}" ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domain:Fruit}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </domain:DtmSelector.WithTree>
            <domain:DtmSelector.WithoutTree>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domain:Tree}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fruits[0].Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </domain:DtmSelector.WithoutTree>
        </domain:DtmSelector>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <TreeView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Trees}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DtmSelector}"                
    />
</UserControl>
```

And in my *DtmSelector.cs*:

```
public class DtmSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate WithTrees { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate WithoutTrees { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        Tree key = item as Tree;
        if (key.Fruits.Count() == 0)
        {
            return WithTrees;
        }
        else
        {
            if (key.Fruits.Select(c=>c.Name).Contains(key.Name))
            {
                return WithTrees;
            }
            else
            {
                return WithoutTrees;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `ViewModel`'s concept is like this:

```
foreach (var item in fruits)
{
    if ( item.Tree == null)
    {
        if (!Trees.Select(c => c.Name).Contains(item.Name))
        {
            Trees.Add(new Tree(item.Name));
        }

        foreach (var tree in Trees.ToList())
        {
            if (tree.Name == item.Name)
            {
                tree.Fruits.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!Trees.Select(c => c.Name).Contains(item.Tree.Name))
        {
            Trees.Add(item.Tree);
        }

        foreach (var tree in Trees.ToList())
        {
            if (tree.Name == item.Tree.Name)
            {
                tree.Fruits.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

This set of codes will check first the `Trees` without its `Fruits` being added. So this line `if (key.Fruits.Count() == 0)` will always return `true`. Is there something I can do? Am I missing something?

I found [an answer from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51288439/12046859) that could help, however, I don't on how this will work on the ViewModel, on how can I select a certain setter by the binded `Property`.

Comment: What exactly are trying to achieve? In order to switch between a `Style` or `Template` you can use [`StyleSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.styleselector?view=netframework-4.8#examples) or [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8#examples). In most scenarios a `Trigger` or `DataTrigger` will also work.

Comment: @BionicCode, I want to use different `ItemSource`'s inside the `TreeView.Resources` using a conditional statement.

Comment: Please be more specific. What is your `ItemsSource`? What are the conditions? Most common scenario is to bind to a view model. If this is the case and the conditions are not UI related then you just have to assign a different collection to the source property directly in the view model. If the conditions are UI related (e.g., a button is pressed) you can use a `ICommand` to trigger the described reassignment of the source property or alternatively use a `DataTrigger`. I can't give you an example as your question is very broad. It's lacking details. Details influence what is the best approach.

Comment: @BionicCode, please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: Thank you. Your question is a good example on how providing more details will lead to a different solution since many assumptions are eliminated. Also more details revealed that your initial approach or strategy was wrong. I posted an answer.

Comment: @BionicCode, thanks for the answer. Your first suggestion is a hack but I can't use since I am already using two Models. So I used your second suggestion with a few tweaks. Please see edited post for the details.

Comment: Please post the complete view model and not just a fragment of method. Otherwise impossible to understand the reason for your uncommented code snippets. It seems like you are heading the wrong way and you didn't fully understand the second suggestion or you are not able to derive a solution for your problem. Please, also show your data structures for the tree. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve with your logic. It looks like you are trying to match names of fruits with names of the tree. Are you sorting? Please we don't know what you are doing, how can we?

Comment: If you want help you really need to provide serious information. The cleanest approach would be to use specialized types for your tree and then select the appropriate `DataTemplate` based on this type. You should introduce the following types: `FruitTree`, `Fruit` and `TreelessFruit` where `FruitTree` has a collection of `Fruit`. If required you can add a `Type` property to all node types that uses an enum `FruitType` to specify the type of fruit and fruit tree (e.g., `FruitTree.Type` and `Fruit.Type`). It's safer to match against strong types than display strings.

Comment: Also when using a `DataTemplateSelector` you don't have to define the `ItemTemplate` for the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. That's what the selector is for. Check my example.

Comment: It is semantically wrong to have a `FruitWithoutTree` defined as a child of `Tree`. See my suggestion regarding the node types from my above comment. I am referring to your `WithoutTree` `DataTemplate` as I don't know the real data structure of your tree since you decided to never share this important piece of information.

Comment: From what I see so far the second suggestion will create exactly the desired output (tree structure) for you (the first suggestion also would do it). Just follow or copy the code. You may rename the `Category` class to `Tree` for your own convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some options here. I will show you two suggestions based on the data structure (model) design.

### First suggestion

Use a single data type for the complete tree structure:

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ViewModel()
  {
    this.Fruits = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>()
    {
      new Fruit("Apple Tree", new ObservableCollection<Fruit>() {new Fruit("Apples")}),
      new Fruit("Mango Tree", new ObservableCollection<Fruit>() {new Fruit("Mangos")}),
      new Fruit("Watermelon")
    }

  ObservableCollection<Fruit> fruits;
  ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruits
  {
    get => this.fruits;
    set
    {
      this.fruits = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation here...
}
```

**Fruit.cs** (data model)

```
class Fruit : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  Fruit(string name) : this(name, new List<Fruit>())
  {
  }

  Fruit(string name, IEnumerable<Fruit> children)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Children = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>(children ?? new List<Fruit>());
  }

  string name;
  string Name 
  {
    get => this.name;
    set
    {
      this.name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  ObservableCollection<Fruit> children;
  ObservableCollection<Fruit> Children 
  {
    get => this.children;
    set
    {
      this.children = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation here...
}
```

**`TreeView` XAML**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <TreeView ItemsSource={Binding Fruits}>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domain:Fruit}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domain:Fruit}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  </TreeView>
</Window>
```

---

### Second suggestion

In case you need different types for the different roles (nodes) you have to make use of a [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8#examples):

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ViewModel()
  {
    this.Fruits = new ObservableCollection<INode>()
    {
      new Category("Apple Tree", new ObservableCollection<INode>() {new Fruit("Apples")}),
      new Category("Mango Tree", new ObservableCollection<INode>() {new Fruit("Mangos")}),
      new Fruit("Watermelon")
    }

  ObservableCollection<INode> fruits;
  ObservableCollection<INode> Fruits
  {
    get => this.fruits;
    set
    {
      this.fruits = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation here...
}
```

**INode.cs** (data model)

```
// Common base type for the node collection and all tree nodes
interface INode: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  string Name {get; set; }

  ObservableCollection<INode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**Category.cs** (data model)

```
class Category : INode
{
  Category(string name) : this(name, new List<INode>())
  {
  }

  Category(string name, IEnumerable<INode> children) 
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Children = new ObservableCollection<INode>(children ?? new List<INode>());
  }

  string name;
  string Name 
  {
    get => this.name;
    set
    {
      this.name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  ObservableCollection<INode> children;
  ObservableCollection<INode> Children 
  {
    get => this.children;
    set
    {
      this.children = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation here...
}
```

**Fruit.cs** (data model)

```
class Fruit : INode
{
  Fruit(string name) : this(name, new List<INode>())
  {
  }

  Fruit(string name, IEnumerable<INode> children)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Children = new ObservableCollection<INode>(children ?? new List<INode>());
  }

  string name;
  string Name 
  {
    get => this.name;
    set
    {
      this.name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  ObservableCollection<INode> children;
  ObservableCollection<INode> Children 
  {
    get => this.children;
    set
    {
      this.children = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation here...
}
```

**NodeTemplateSelector.cs**

```
class NodeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemlplate CategoryNodeTemplate { get; set; }
  public DataTemlplate FruitNodeTemplate { get; set; }

  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    switch (item)
    {
        case Category _:
           return this.CategoryNodeTemplate;
        case Fruit _:
           return this.FruitNodeTemplate;
        default:
           return this.FruitNodeTemplate;
    }
  }
}
```

**`TreeView` XAML**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
    <NodeTemplateSelector x:Key="NodeTemplateSelector">
      <NodeTemplateSelector.CategoryNodeTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Category}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </NodeTemplateSelector.CategoryNodeTemplate>
      <NodeTemplateSelector.FruitNodeTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Fruit}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </NodeTemplateSelector.FruitNodeTemplate>
    </NodeTemplateSelector>
  </Window.Resources>

  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}" 
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource NodeTemplateSelector}"  />
</Window>
```

Comment: From this `<NodeTemplateSelector x:Key="NodeTemplateSelector">`, is this the `NodeTemplateSelector` class that you create?

Comment: Yes. That's the way to create an instance of the object in XAML. The Key is required since the instance is defined inside a `ResourceDictionary`>

Comment: Regarding your error: you have to modify my XAML code to meet your conditions. You need to remove the `Window` tag. I just added it to show how to assign the `DataContext` and use of the `ResourceDictionary` to declare the templates.